# (SVG) How to collect all the 'd' codes?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, svg

I am trying to create an interactive map of the world.

Users will be assigned a nation.

To do this, I want to insert all the `d=''` codes into a database.

It is currently consisted of tens of bits of code like this:

```
<path class="COUNTRYNAME" d="123.123.123"></path>
```

Ideally, I would like a program that would be able to select the `d=''` codes and insert them into my database, using PHP/JS/SQL preferably.

Is this possible?

**What I have tried:**

Manually copying and pasting the `d=''` into the database. It works but is incredibly time consuming.

Comment: Please provide some detail or an example of the source file that provides these 'd' codes, it will greatly affect the solution that we provide to you. At this point I am not convinced you not are asking us to screen scrape data for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript can navigate the DOM and pull out the data from the element, then use AJAX to send it to your server.

```
var paths = $('path[class="COUNTRYNAME"]');
$.each(paths, function(index, current){
    //loop through each found
    var d = $(this).attr('d').val();
    var params = "d=" + d;
    $.post("/script.php", params, function(response){
        //handle response here
    });
});
```

If you are trying to crawl someone elses website, then I recommend a headless browser or making custom a web crawler.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a tiny bit of code, please? Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel that's not how this site works. Write your solution and if and when you get stuck ask a question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Like said, we can't provide the full program. Here are some hints :

You may want to use jQuery, which allows easier DOM manipulation. You can then iterate through all items with "d" attribute :

`var data=[];
$("div[d]").each(function(){
data[]=$(this).attr("d")
}`

You can store their data in an array, and then throw that info to a PHP script that will handle the storage. You have to use `$.ajax()` for this.